# "Path must be document-level" in firestore rules playground. Why?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm learning how to set up the rules for Firestore.

I want to simulate a request of a collection, but it shows an error ("Path must be document-level") and doesn't let me run the request:

[image: 1]

Why is it so? It is a very common thing to request a collection of documents from their API, so why can I not simulate it in the playground?

Here are the rules I'm testing. They don't exactly work, but that's a different question:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId}/todos {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "*why can I not simulate it in the playground*" - that can only be answered by the engineers who designed the tool.  What you have here sounds like a feature request for Firebase, not a question for the volunteers of Stack Overflow.  I suggest filing a request with [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if one can fetch an entire Collection, a *match* statement in Security Rules must specify a document path, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure?hl=en&authuser=0#basic_readwrite_rules):

> All match statements should point to documents, *not collections*. A
> match statement can point to a specific document, as in match
> `/cities/SF` or use wildcards to point to any document in the specified
> path, as in match `/cities/{city}`.

So, in the simulator, you must specify a document path and therefore check your rule for a specific document.

---

And don't forget another important point which is somehow linked to the above: [Rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters)

Comment: The OP is asking why it's not possible to simulate a collection query (not just a single document get), which is still governed by security rules.  The console does not give you this capability, just single documents.  It's kind of a missing feature and can only be resolved by Firebase.

Comment: Also I'll point out that a collection query is not the same as an individual document get.  Your answer is suggesting that you can just pick some random document ID in order to test a rule, but this is not at all the same thing as a collection query, and will not be able to test `list` type rules that only work for queries.  A functionally complete rule tester in the console would allow a collection query with filters in order to fully exercise rules.  Right now you can only do this with the emulator suite.

Comment: You are right, this is just a trick. I therefore removed it from the answer (which BTW I cannot delete since it is accepted)

Answer (score 1):

Your question:

> Why is it so? It is a very common thing to request a collection of documents from their API, so why can I not simulate it in the playground?

Has an unfortunate answer.  It's just not implemented in the console. The playground you're using only works with single document operations and can't test collection queries.  You can file a ticket with [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) to indicate you're interested in this feature.  However, I wouldn't expect this to happen any time soon because there is already another tool that can do this.

You can use the [Firebase Emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) to [test security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator) before deployment.  You can write arbitrarily complex queries in JavaScript, put them in a test harness, and run them quickly and repeatedly without having to enter new data for each query.